# Stepstone - Material Stepper

Tags: android, github, uistepper

[Github : Stepstone Material Stepper](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper)

Anybody using this?
I just want to ask, I have more than 4 Edittexts inside a step, and each of it has verifation method. I just want to know where should I call those error trapping methods in my activity?

Example of my verification method is here:

```
 class VerifyAppNameTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    // use doInBackground() to make network calls, the returned value is
    // sent to onPostExecute()
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... data) {

        if (data[0].replace(" ","").isEmpty())
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "1";
        }
        else if (data[0].length() > 25)
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "2";
        }
        else if (checkAppName(data[0]))
        {
            f1 = true;
            return "3";
        }
        else
        {
            f1 = false;
            return "4";
        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tilAppName.setErrorEnabled(true);
        switch(result)
        {
            case "1":   {tilAppName.setError("You can't leave this empty.");break;}
            case "2":   {tilAppName.setError("Maximum of 25 characters.");break;}
            case "3":   {tilAppName.setError("No spaces allowed");break;}
            case "4":   {tilAppName.setError(null);tilAppName.setErrorEnabled(false);break;}

        }

    }
}
```

another one is this

```
public boolean edtAppCategoryET(String data)
{

    tilAppCategory.setErrorEnabled(true);
    if (data.replace(" ","").equals(""))
    {
        tilAppCategory.setError("You can't leave this empty.");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        tilAppCategory.setError("");
        tilAppCategory.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is the code for stepper

```
public class AppUploadStep1 extends Fragment implements Step {

private static final String LAYOUT_RESOURCE_ID_ARG_KEY = "messageResourceId";

EditText edtAppName, edtAppVersion, edtAppPlatform, edtAppCategory, edtAppDescription;
TextInputLayout  tilAppName,  tilAppVersion,  tilAppPlatform,  tilAppCategory,  tilAppDescription;
String sAppName, sAppVersion, sAppPlatform, sAppCategory, sAppDescription;
boolean f1, f2, f3, f4, f5;

HttpURLConnection connection;
BufferedReader reader;
URL url;
InputStream stream;
StringBuffer buffer;
String line;

ProgressBar loading;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_app_upload_step1, container, false);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    //initialize your UI
    edtAppPlatform = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtAppPlatform);
    edtAppVersion = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtAppVersion);
    edtAppCategory = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtAppCategory);
    edtAppDescription = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtAppDescription);
    edtAppName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edtAppName);

    tilAppName = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tilAppName);
    tilAppVersion = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tilAppVersion);
    tilAppPlatform = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tilAppPlatform);
    tilAppCategory = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tilAppCategory);
    tilAppDescription = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tilAppDescription);

    edtAppPlatform.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showCustomSpinnerDialog(v, R.array.spinner_platform, R.id.edtAppPlatform);
        }
    });

    edtAppCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showCustomSpinnerDialog(v, R.array.categories, R.id.edtAppCategory);
        }
    });

    errorTrap();
    return v;
}

public static AppUploadStep1 newInstance(@LayoutRes int layoutResId) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(LAYOUT_RESOURCE_ID_ARG_KEY, layoutResId);
    AppUploadStep1 fragment = new AppUploadStep1();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}



@Override
public VerificationError verifyStep() {


//    getData();
    //if (edtAppVersionET(sAppVersion)) {
      //  return true
     //   ?new VerificationError("Password cannot be empty")
     //   :null;
return null;
}

@Override
public void onSelected() {

}

@Override
public void onError(@NonNull VerificationError error) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already got the answer but here's what i did:

In verifystep method check the conditions for your edittext and return VerificationError("") at the end (it is in kotlin)

```
if(editText?.text?.toString().isNullOrEmpty()){
    editText?.setError("this field is required")
    editText?.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

      override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

      override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                editText?.setError("this field is required")
                }

      override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                editText?.setError(null)
            }
        })
        return VerificationError("")
}
```